# Calculating the sum of vectors

Tags: numpy

I have two matrices `a` and `b` and would like to calculate all the sums between them into a tensor. How can I do this more efficiently than doing the following code:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[4,5],[6,7]])

n1 = a.shape[0]
n2 = b.shape[0]
f = a.shape[1]
c = np.zeros((n1,n2,f))

c = np.zeros((n1,n2,f))
for i in range(n1):
    for j in range(n2):
        c[i,j,:] = a[i,:] + b[j,:]
```

einstein-sum and the like does obviously not work and an outer product neither - is there an appropriate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your loop expression into a broadcasting one:

```
c[i,j,:] = a[i,:] + b[j,:]
c[i,j,:] = a[i,None,:] + b[None,j,:]  # fill in the missing dimensions
c = a[:,None,:] + b[None,:,:]


In [167]: a[:,None,:]+b[None,:,:]                                                                              
Out[167]: 
array([[[ 5,  7],
        [ 7,  9]],

       [[ 7,  9],
        [ 9, 11]],

       [[ 9, 11],
        [11, 13]]])
In [168]: _.shape                                                                                            
Out[168]: (3, 2, 2)
```

`a[:,None]+b` does the same thing, since leading `None` (`np.newaxis`) are automatic, and trailing `:` also.

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasting and add extra dimensions using advanced indexing:

```
a[:,None,:]+b[None,:,:]
```